# Auto update template string value without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

So, when I refresh the page, the template string is updated to it's new value which is pulled from the database and is ever so changing.

**Is there a way that I can use ajax or something similar to auto refresh the value of the template string?**

This is the template string here:

[image]

It's being pulled from a GET request which performs a database lookup of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to use ajax. Then, the value need to be set inside an element (like div, span). And you make a page to write updated value (get from database and write it out). Use ajax to update value from the page to element.

Comment: When I use a GET ajax request for the route that contains the template string and performs the database lookup, it auto GETS the page every 3 seconds (or whatever I set it to) but the template string value is not changing on the page until I make a physical page refresh.

Comment: 1) You make a script that auto call ajax update after 3 seconds (just use setTimeout, setInterval of js). 2) You need to set no-cache on both page (the page that calls ajax and the page that write data).

Comment: I set cache to false in the ajax call. Where else do I do this? In the GET route?

Comment: Okay so I did this in the GET route where the template string is rendered: `res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");`. Still not working.

Comment: You must test: 1) run the page update data (the page that ajax call) - will it work normally? 2) Test your page. Will it have any errors? 3) if 1-normally works, 2 - no error. So you need clear all browser cache. Run it again.

Comment: Yeah, not working still. No errors or anything either. Gonna have to find another way to do this I guess.

Comment: Give me the code of PHP page, and the ajax function that you call. One again, the php page work normally? (I mean it shows up result).

Comment: I'm using node.js not php.

Comment: nothing different. Then you give me the code js of page that you write out the result and the ajax function that you call. Can you get right result on the page that you write data?

Comment: `function autoRefresh() {
    $.get({
      url: "/users/dashboard",
      cache: false
    }, function(data, status) {
      setTimeout(autoRefresh, 3000);
    });
  };
  autoRefresh();`

Comment: `router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.passport.user, (err, doc) => {
    var messages = req.flash('error');
    var credits = parseFloat(doc.credits).toFixed(2);
    if(credits === 'NaN') {
      credits = 0;
    }
    Bid.findById('591d050710ce46129966d84c', function(err, bid) {
      var bid = bid.currentBid;
      var bidPlusFive = bid + 5;
      res.render('users/dashboard', {user: req.user.email, credits: credits, messages: messages, bid: bid, bidPlusFive: bidPlusFive, hasErrors: messages.length > 0});
    });
  });
});`

Comment: Can you see the right result for second part of code?

Comment: I see the right result and it gets updated correctly on page refresh. The auto refresh is working too as I can see it in the console, but it's not changing/updating the value of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this syntax to call ajax:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "the_page_that_you_write_out_the_right_result",
      cache: false
    }).done(function(html) {
        $( "#the_id_of_tag_that_you_want_to_display_result" ).append(html);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: It's working, sorta. The append is messing up the page though. It looks like this: https://snag.gy/ZjVPoU.jpg and it adds the entire page to the page on every interval rather than just changing the <span> that I set the ID to.

Comment: I think it's because it's appending the entire dashboard page to the bottom of the HTML on each interval.

Comment: You mean it works fine, just the result is "append" not "replace, or update".  And the page will be longer longer after time interval. Right?